# Expanding Window in Out-Of-Sample forecast with OLS

Tags: r, regression, forecasting

My data set is stored in "ts_monthly". This dataset is pretty large (1812 rows x 28 columns) and is a time series.

here are the first 20 rows:

```
ts_monthly  <- matrix(
  c(
    187101, 187102, 187103, 187104, 187105, 187106, 187107, 187108, 187109,
    187110, 187111, 187112, 187201, 187202, 187203, 187204, 187205, 187206,
    187207, 187208, 4.44, 4.5, 4.61, 4.74, 4.86, 4.82, 4.73, 4.79, 4.84, 4.59,
    4.64, 4.74, 4.86, 4.88, 5.04, 5.18, 5.18, 5.13, 5.1, 5.04, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26,
    0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.2633, 0.2667, 0.27,
    0.2733, 0.2767, 0.28, 0.2833, 0.2867, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4,
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4025, 0.405, 0.4075, 0.41, 0.4125, 0.415, 0.4175, 0.42,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.004967, 0.004525, 0.004252, 0.004643, 0.003698,
    0.003373, 0.003255, 0.003713, 0.004554, 0.007041, 0.006488, 0.006975,
    0.005764, 0.005218, 0.006001, 0.00603, 0.004953, 0.004067, 0.004399, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.83772802441074, -2.85115104474288,
    -2.87530150497517, -2.90311078367359, -2.92811208587901, -2.91984757602912,
    -2.90099885047045, -2.91360405938943, -2.92398836869515, -2.87095367203906,
    -2.88178801420477, -2.90311078367359, -2.91549965039228, -2.90677606765922,
    -2.92673940206704, -2.94199024231951, -2.92962644846065, -2.90807133499557,
    -2.89048941187595, -2.86672498817609, NA, -2.83772802441074,
    -2.85115104474288, -2.87530150497517, -2.90311078367359, -2.92811208587901,
    -2.91984757602912, -2.90099885047045, -2.91360405938943, -2.92398836869515,
    -2.87095367203906, -2.88178801420477, -2.89049834818686, -2.90266928570657,
    -2.89447853984882, -2.91459126813139, -2.92962644846065, -2.91777073208428,
    -2.89635453132834, -2.87855944582309, -2.40694510831829, -2.42036812865043,
    -2.44451858888271, -2.47232786758114, -2.49732916978656, -2.48906465993666,
    -2.470215934378, -2.48282114329698, -2.4932054526027, -2.44017075594661,
    -2.45100509811232, -2.47232786758114, -2.49109862003592, -2.48901343174065,
    -2.5151204283845, -2.53640317555518, -2.53032412947879, -2.51458241793412,
    -2.50271127442151, -2.484906649788, -0.430782916092454, -0.430782916092454,
    -0.430782916092454, -0.430782916092454, -0.430782916092454,
    -0.430782916092454, -0.430782916092454, -0.430782916092454,
    -0.430782916092454, -0.430782916092454, -0.430782916092454,
    -0.430782916092454, -0.424401030356354, -0.417762635918571,
    -0.411618973682543, -0.405587066764331, -0.399302318981855,
    -0.393488917061449, -0.387778137454439, -0.38181833838809, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  nrow = 20L,
  ncol = 28L,
  dimnames = list(
    NULL,
    c(
      "yyyymm", "Index", "D12", "E12", "b.m", "tbl", "AAA", "BAA",
      "lty", "ntis", "Rfree", "infl", "ltr", "corpr", "svar", "csp",
      "CRSP_SPvw", "CRSP_SPvwx", "log_eqp", "eqp", "dp", "dy", "ep",
      "de", "tms", "dfy", "dfr", "log_eqpt1"
    )
  )
)
```

I would like to make Out of sample forecast using an Ordinary Least Squares model. So far I have the following code, but I would like to insert an expanding/recursive window:

```
monthly_IS = monthly %>%
  filter(yyyymm < 199201)

monthly_OOS = monthly %>%
  filter(yyyymm >= 199201)

model1 <- lm(log_eqpt1 ~ dp + de + tms, data = monthlyIS, na.action = na.omit)

prediction = predict (model1, monthlyOOS %>% select(dp, de, tms))

rmse = data.frame(monthly_OOS$log_eqpt1)

rmse = rmse %>%
  mutate(prediction = prediction)

summary(model1)

model1
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am also not familiar with the theoretical procedure of Out of sample forecasting via OLS, so even just a theoretical explanation of the steps is welcome.

Thanks!